# CRM 2013 Black / Metro Top Menu Bar not changing

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

So I know this is probably a really simple question but I can't figure out how others are getting the black background on the top menu nav bar in crm 2013. You can see examples of what I mean [here](http://www.preact.co.uk/preact_blog/orion-update-previewing-the-new-microsoft-dynamics-crm-interface) and [here](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20130905/hands-on-with-metro-fied-orion-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013/) and ....

It seems everyone knows how to do it but me??

I have set my crm user to high contrast no difference. I set my windows theme to high contrast no go. I downloaded ie & chrome high contrast skins and that didn't work either??

I am using IE 11 as well as 10 (in a vm) both behave the same.
I am using Chrome 31.0.1650.63

So slap me with a 2X4 if needed cause I don't know what I am missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change in the background color was a result of UR 1 being applied.

Black = RTM

Grey = UR1

Comment: Ohhh lame so no way to get it back then...? I wonder if there is a key in the registry or the db you can toggle to use the rtm stylesheet?

Comment: The change was made to provide more contrast, trying to change it back  would be unsupported at best :(